# PE relocations and runtime instruction offsets

Tags: c, winapi, portable-executable

I'm trying to reverse runtime addresses to their `objdump -dl` addresses to create a sampling profiler. What I'm running into compiling under GCC 11.1, is that the PE image is loaded at a different location which I can retrieve with `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`, but if I subtract that address from the `rip` instruction address retrieved with `GetThreadContext`, I get a much larger number than I expect. I would expect it to be a fairly small value based on the number of instructions in the program, but I get something like `0x69CAFF3F4` as the delta.

```
Base Address = 140698825588736

Instr Address   [Instr Addr Hex  ] [Instr - Base]
-----------------------------------------------------
140727224168436 [00007FFD9C34EFF4] [000000069CAFEFF4]
```

Comment: Are you sure you are looking within the right module?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I believe so. It's using the CreateToolhelp32Snapshot from the same Process ID.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the reference! It is being suspended first and it seems VerySleepy takes [the same approach](https://github.com/VerySleepy/verysleepy/blob/4549e4eac5738948c18cd9e497b229ca41ab0a49/src/profiler/profiler.cpp#L176). A strange thing is some of the instructions are at the expected position, but then others at those much higher addresses.

Comment: Yes, but a process has many modules, each starting at their own load address.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I think you're right. It looks like there's other DLL modules in the process that are around those addresses.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there were 43 other DLLs in the module list retrieved using `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` and then iterating on them with `Module32Next`. 42 of them were above the address 0x7FFD00000000 which was producing the large delta between the invoked executable's load address of 0x29B92700.